# Run time problem with an example of a personal Microsoft Teams application

Tags: node.js, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams, microsoft-identity-platform

I'm studying to add SSO functions in a Teams personal application by using this example, https://github.com/pnp/teams-dev-samples/tree/master/samples/tab-sso. I chosed the version node.js. I registered the application on Azure-AD platform, I uploaded the manifest and .env files, and I ran npm install in both api and npmjs folder. But when I run "npm run start" in the nodejs folder, I hade this problem. Do you have any idea why there is a problem and how can I resolve it? Any help is appreciated. Thanks! [Log of the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTbq8.png)

Comment: Hi @yucongzhao, did your npm install complete successfully?

Comment: Not really, but I tried with the application generated directly by Microsoft Teams Toolkit which is a plug-in in Visual Studio Code. With the option Azure AD SSO on, I can now build my personal Teams SSO Tab :)

Comment: Great!! Moving this to answer for better visibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reinstall modules. Alternatively, you can use Microsoft Teams Toolkit with the option Azure AD SSO on.